# Button function full screen iframe webview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button, webview, android-jetpack-compose

How can I call function for onShowCustomView?
I tried to add a button, but when I clicked the button(FullScreenButton), it didn't go full screen, and nothing happened.I new in android development, need help.

```
@Composable
fun Stream(activity: ComponentActivity) {
    val frameVideo = "<html><body><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"320\" src=\"https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/168/original/Record.mp4\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
    val state = rememberWebViewState(url = frameVideo)
    val navigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
    val chromeClient = remember { CustomChromeClient(activity) }


    WebView(
        state = rememberWebViewStateWithHTMLData(data = frameVideo),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        navigator = navigator,
        chromeClient = chromeClient, //This is what concerns us for fullscreen mode
        onCreated = { webView ->
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
            webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8")
        }
    )

    FullScreenButton{
        val FullScreenFn = CustomChromeClient(this)

    }
}

@Composable
fun FullScreenButton(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Column {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(400.dp))
        Button(onClick = { 
        val client = CustomChromeClient(activity)
        client.onShowCustomView(view, callback) }) {
            Text("Full Screen")
        }}
}

class CustomChromeClient(val activity: ComponentActivity): AccompanistWebChromeClient() {

    var customView: View? = null

    override fun onHideCustomView() {
        (activity.window.decorView as FrameLayout).removeView(this.customView)
        this.customView = null

    }

    override fun onShowCustomView(paramView: View, paramCustomViewCallback: CustomViewCallback) {
        if (this.customView != null) {
            onHideCustomView()
            return
        }
        this.customView = paramView
        (activity.window.decorView as FrameLayout).addView(this.customView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1))
    }

}
```

I expect that when I click the button, it will go full screen.